# Do I have to call Dispose method on FolderBrowserDialog?

Tags: .net, idisposable

The `FolderBrowserDialog` component in .NET Framework (and the `OpenFileDialog`) implements the `IDisposible` interface, meaning we should call its `Dispose` method at some appropriate time after we've done with it or something bad happens (unmanaged resource leaks).

In Visual Studio WinForm designer, if I drag a `FolderBrowserDialog` component onto a Form, the code generated by the designer does not seem to take care of this at all, no code calls the Dispose method on the `FolderBrowserDialog`.

In contrast, if I drag a `Timer` (the one in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace) which also implements `IDisposible` interface, the code generated would be:

```
this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
```

By associating the timer with the container (this.components), the timer is guaranteed to be properly disposed when the container is disposed- happens when `Form.Close()` or `Form.Dispose()` is called.

So why `FolderBrowserDialog` component receives this special treatment?

Comment: All of the shell dialog class wrappers only have a Dispose() method because they inherit one from their Component base class.  They don't actually require disposal, their unmanaged resources get disposed internally when the native dialog closes.  @thecoop correctly explained how they avoid having Dispose() called.

Comment: Hi Hans(nobugz), good to see you in SO. Looking into Reflector, I find a call to NativeWindow.DestroyHandle() in FolderBrowserDialog's RunDialog method, so I think you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good spot! The reason is probably that the `FolderBrowserDialog` does not provide a constructor that takes an `IContainer` argument, whereas `Timer` does.

As to why this is so, you can only ask the original winforms designers. Maybe it isn't really designed to be used in the designer in this way? They only meant it to be used in code in a `using` statement?

Bear in mind that `FolderBrowserDialog`, and its parents, don't actually override `Dispose` from `Component`, so it doesn't actually *need* to dispose anything.